# How to make a webpage mobile friendly with css media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have added some css media queries but it doesn't seem to make any change, I mean I have added this code

```
@media screen and (min-width:10px) and (max-width:640px) {
.leftSideBar{display:none !important;}
.rightSideBar{display:none !important;}
}
```

but the left and right sidebars are still visible i have also tried changing the range of min-width and max-width it still doesn't make any difference, am i missing something here ? do i have to add something more than this in my css to make it work ?

below given is my default css for both classes

```
.leftSideBar{display:block !important;}
.rightSideBar{display:block !important;}
```

Comment: Have you set the viewport? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Yes i have this one right "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dm4eryfz/ i have tried your code and its working fine. you check by resizing window in fiddle.

to further debug the issue, can you please share the HTML or the complete CSS?

Comment: Any reason you're using !important for your default classes? If you use it liberally, it could be other rules overriding your media query style down the stylesheet. Make sure the default rules are in the stylesheet before the media query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My advice would be to test the code in a real mobile phone not with a browser if that's what you are doing cause browsers behave differently

Another important thing you must do is add meta view port tag without that it won't work like the one given below

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Remove !important from your default css use css specificity instead if its really necessary so your default css should be

```
.leftSideBar{display:block;}
.rightSideBar{display:block;}
```

if even that doesn't work you have to show us your entire css or html to identify the problem

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine in your code.
Try with this meta in your html :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Also, if I can give you a little advice, try the mobile first way. It looks like this :

```
.leftSideBar{display:none !important;}
.rightSideBar{display:none !important;}

@media screen and (min-width:640px) {
  /*design for screen-width >= 640px */
}
```

This gives a priority on mobile devices so computers will be set as the exception in order to have less code executed on mobile devices which are quite less powerful than a computer ;)
here is a little / great tutorial on mobile first approach :
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Good luck and give your html and full css if it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The `min-width` and `!important` are probably useless. The query is fine, but it may be shortned to just:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.leftSideBar, .rightSideBar {display:none}
}
```

Should be working either way. Are you sure the html is fine? You may want to show that here as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code is the best for mobile friendly responsive web:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```